# Java Try & Catch example

Tags: java, try-catch

So I have this code right here but I do not understand why my Try statement is underlined.When I hover over it, it says b3 is already defined in method main. What would I have to do to make it work the way it is shown. ( Everything Else works)

```
public class ReviewTest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
boxes b1 = new boxes();
System.out.printf("My first Box = %s\n", b1.toString());
System.out.printf("My first Box = %s\n", b1);

boxes b2 = new boxes(10.0, 12.4, 13.9);
System.out.printf("My second Box = %s\n" , b2);

System.out.printf("The volumne of b2 = %.3f\n", b2.volume());
System.out.printf("The surface Area of b2 = %.3f\n", b2.surfaceArea());

boxes b3 = null;

try {
   boxes b3 = new boxes(-1,4.3, 12);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
{
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}       
}
```

Comment: What do you think _is already defined_ means?

Comment: And indeed it is.  You don't need the `boxes b3` bit in your try block, just `b3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you *have* defined `b3`. What you need to do to fix this is this:

Right before your try/catch block, you defined `boxes b3 = null;`. What you need to do is go to inside your `try` block, and remove the `boxes` part before `b3 = new boxes(-1,4.3, 12);`.

Answer (score 0):

please change 
        `boxes b3 = new boxes(-1,4.3, 12);`
on
        `b3 = new boxes(-1,4.3, 12);`